# How do I link new file in my view to a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller `test_controller`an this controller has a view `test` with an `index.html.erb`. 
The index is accessible by /test/.

Now I want to add a new view file to this controller (so I can access the variables set in it), say `hello.html.erb` and it should be available by /test/hello. I put it in the same views folder as my `test` index.htlm.erb is.

My current `routes.rb` entry looks like this:

```
scope "/test/" do
  match "/hello" => "test#hello", :controller => "test"
  match "/" => 'test#index'
end
```

I am able to call `/test/hello`but I can't access my variables from test_controller. Why is this and how can I fix it?

### EDIT:

`test_controller` looks like this:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  layout 'test'

  def index

    @error_logs = Error.order('creationTimestamp DESC')

  end
```

And I want to access `@error_logs` from the `hello` view.

Comment: Are you setting those variables in `hello` action handler?

Comment: Perhaps amend your question to include your controller code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Im not quite sure what you mean

Comment: @Zois: isn't there a `def hello` in your controller?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No there is not

Comment: That's weird. It should fail with error about not found action.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, the action's not necessary if he's **not** doing anything like setting up variables within it.

Comment: Just tried it and it works perfectly! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set up a controller for the hello action and set the variables that you need in that - for example to have access to the last_error in the hello view something like:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  layout 'test'

  def index
    @error_logs = Error.order('creationTimestamp DESC')
  end

  def hello
    @last_error = Error.last 
  end 
end
```